# Pymysql Lost connection to MySQL server during query

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, pymysql

I trying to run a simple query on a server using pymsql which shouldnt be an issue. Im virtually pulling my hair now. What am I missing.

```
 import pymysql

 connection = pymysql.connect(user='mak_aba', passwd='password',host='localhost',database='baba')

 cursor = connection.cursor(buffered=True)

 query = ("SELECT * FROM `orders`")

 cursor.execute(query)

 for item in cursor:
   print item
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you forgot to set port
try this

`connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', port=3306, user='mak_aba', passwd='password', db='baba')`

here [example](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/blob/master/example.py)

try this

```
import pymysql

connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', port=3306, user='mak_aba', passwd='password', db='baba')

cursor = connection.cursor()

query = ("SELECT * FROM `orders`")

cursor.execute(query)

for item in cursor:
    print(item)
```

Comment: Stil same with the port.

Comment: try `cursor = connection.cursor()` without `buffered=True` it worked for me